# How to get access to struct in one class from another?

Tags: c++

How can I get access to randomStruct in class B?

```
Class A
{
 public:
  struct randomStruct
   {
    // some functions and variables here
   }
}

Class B
{
// and here I need to call my randomStruct from class A
}
```

This is just an example of code

Comment: `A::randomstruct`??

Comment: You cannot "call a struct". Please post real code

Answer (score 0):

If you by call mean use this could be a solution

```
Class A
{
 public:
  struct randomStruct
   {
    // some functions and variables here
   }
}

Class B
{
// and here I need to call my randomStruct from class A
  A::randomStruct myRandomStruct;  // use the public definition in A
}
```